# Install Docker CE on Ubuntu 15.04 Vivid

Tags: ubuntu, docker, ubuntu-15.04

I have Ubuntu 15.04 Vivid.
I need to use Docker CE v17.03

According to the [docker docks](http://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntu/) I need to have one of the following Ubuntu distributions: Yakkety, Xenial or Trusty to install the Docker CE on it. The installation process for Vivid fails, because there are no dedicated packages for it.

Is there any tricky workaround for this problem?

Comment: That distribution has lost support because has ended its life. I recommend upgrade Ubuntu if it Is possible

Comment: Hate to be that guy, but Vivid has been EOL for over a year, upgrade. Although having said that, I'm sure you can just copy the binaries and have it work fine.

Comment: Thank you guys. Finally I upgraded and it works.